# How to remove charset from Content-type when using HttpServletResponse in Struts

Tags: java, servlets, response, httpresponse, content-type

I'm trying to send a response with "application/json" content-type. The server only accepts this content-type.

But when I try to set the content-type, it automatically adds "charset=ISO-8859-1" and this is causing problems. Is there a way to remove it?

I've added the code of how I'm setting the content-type and getting the writer in HttpServletResponse.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().println(json);
```

I need the content-type to be just "application/json".

Comment: Of course, the receiver should really be standards compliant; specifying the character set should not pose problems. If it only accepts a specific char set then it should at least accept *that* char set in the `Content-Type` header...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm trying to verify my domain in azure portal. I need to have a JSON in a particular url. Upto this point my work is done. But the verification failed due to content-type being wrong. I was told that my content-type should only contain "application/json". That's what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: Typical of Mickeysoft not to keep to standards *again*. Sheesh. Regardless, that's not your problem, I've already upvoted the question; unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The verification steps seems to be introduced a few months ago. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(res.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
outputStream.flush();
```